# Check data in the picker swift

Tags: swift

When there is no data in the Picker, the application shuts down when I press the OK button. The OK button does not work when there is no data in the picker. How can I do this? When there is no data in the pickerda right now, the application gives error when I press OK.  `block (dataArray[selectedvalueindex], Selectedvalueindex)` I get

> Fatal Error: index out of range error in this code sale.

```
 toolBar.didSelectDone = {

                if let block = didSelectValue {

                    let selectedValueIndex = optionPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)

                    block(dataArray[selectedValueIndex], selectedValueIndex)
                }

                remove()
                }

 class func selectOption(title: String = "",
                            hideCancel: Bool = false,
                            dataArray:Array<String>?,
                            selectedIndex: Int? = nil,
                            didSelectValue : ((_ value: String, _ atIndex: Int)->())?)  {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your dataArray has a value for the selectedIndex

```
if selectedValueIndex < dataArray.count {
   block(dataArray[selectedValueIndex], selectedValueIndex)
}
```